# gdb No source file named input.c

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries, graphviz

I'm trying to debug [Graphviz 2.34.0](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/blfs/conglomeration/graphviz/) after having built it from source with configure+make.

Here is the gdb script I'm using:

```
####################
# Pagination = off #
####################
set pagination off

#######################
# Initial breakpoints #
####################### 
dir /home/oren/GIT/klee/benchmarks/graphviz/graphviz-2.34.0/lib/cgraph
dir /home/oren/GIT/klee/benchmarks/graphviz/graphviz-2.34.0/lib/common
start
break input.c:570
break grammar.c:1281
break dot.c:210
run
```

But for some reason gdb fails to add 2 of the 3 breakpoints.
(at first it looked like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388639/problems-with-setting-breakpoints-in-a-gdb-sciprt) but I've added the start and no change):

```
No source file named input.c.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]
No source file named grammar.c.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]
```

When I try to stepi my way through I get this:

```
210     while ((G = gvNextInputGraph(Gvc))) {
(gdb) stepi
0x0000000000400fba  210     while ((G = gvNextInputGraph(Gvc))) {
(gdb) stepi
0x0000000000400be0 in gvNextInputGraph@plt ()
(gdb) stepi
0x0000000000400be6 in gvNextInputGraph@plt ()
(gdb) stepi
0x0000000000400beb in gvNextInputGraph@plt ()
(gdb) stepi
0x0000000000400b80 in ?? ()
(gdb) stepi
0x0000000000400b86 in ?? ()
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

## EDIT:

I tried building without shared libraries with:

```
../graphviz-2.34.0/configure --disable-shared
```

And the package builds without errors, but some executables (including mine) are missing. So I guess this option is not on the table (?)
After that I tried setting the variable LD_BIND_NOW:

```
LD_BIND_NOW=1 gdb -x ./gdbCommands.txt --args ./build2/cmd/dot/.libs/dot -Tjpeg -oInput.jpeg Input.txt
```

And then I get (with either step or stepi):

```
(gdb) stepi
0x0000000000400fba  210     while ((G = gvNextInputGraph(Gvc))) {
(gdb) 
0x0000000000400be0 in gvNextInputGraph@plt ()
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7b7e200 in gvNextInputGraph () from /usr/lib/libgvc.so.6
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7b7e202 in gvNextInputGraph () from /usr/lib/libgvc.so.6
```

Then I also ask info sharedlibrary and get:

```
(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7ddab00  0x00007ffff7df5660  Yes         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007ffff7b601a0  0x00007ffff7bb04b8  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/libgvc.so.6
0x00007ffff792e310  0x00007ffff7938722  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/libcgraph.so.6
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

Comment: Most likely graphviz shared library was built without debug info.

Comment: @ks1322, old CFLAGS=-g -O2 ... so I re-did the build with CFLAGS=-ggdb ../graphviz.2.34.0/configure but the result is still the same ... also, since I am able to debug one of the three files (dot.c) it might be some other thing ...

Comment: Could you also post output of `info sharedlibrary` before you tried `stepi`, OS version, compiler version, gdb version?

Comment: @ks1322, I've added info sharedlibrary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I try to stepi my way through I get this:

The problem is that you are stepping into the code inside dynamic loader -- code responsible for resolving *imported* symbols, such as `gvNextInputGraph@plt` to their definition in a shared library.

The code in dynamic loader lacks debug info (and is not the code you want to be stepping through anyway).

Several ways around this:

1. Don't use `stepi`, use `step` (this will stop inside the called function).
2. Use step the *first* time you encounter this function. After the first time, the function will have been resolved, and you can use `stepi`.
3. Set `LD_BIND_NOW=1` in the environment. This will cause dynamic loader to resolve all the symbols at startup time, so by the time you execute your `stepi`s, the symbol will already be resolved.
4. Build your executable without shared libraries (so that everything is linked into the main binary) -- the loader will then have nothing to resolve.

**Update:**

I only answered the "why is stepi weird" part of the question, but your main question is "why aren't breakpoints getting set".

The answer is: your build of `libgvc.so.6` (where you are trying to set breakpoints) is missing debug info.

There are two likely possibilities:

1. You are debugging *system* provided version in `/usr/lib/` rather than the version you built, or
2. When you do `make install`, the library is stripped.

To fix #1, use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to your own version.
To fix #2, use the "as built" version using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (i.e. same as above), or change `Makefile` to not strip. Running

```
make install STRIP=/bin/true
```

may also work.

Comment: Yes! Iwas indeed debugging the system version! When I did "sudo make install" for my freshly built version I can now debug it! thanks a lot!!